# Funtoriality of twisted K-theory

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology, stable-homotopy, homology, parameterized-homotopy

*I posted this question on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3337533/functoriality-of-twisted-k-theory), but received no answer there.*

In order to avoid the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) I will first state what I want, then what I think is the solution and how that failed until now.

I'm trying to use May–Sigurdsson's definition of Twisted $K$-theory, since the twisted $K$-homology comes more natural that way.

## Actual question:

The following is an excerpt (proof of Proposition 2.1) from the paper

> Mehdi Khorami, *A universal coefficient theorem for twisted $K$-theory*, J. Topol. 4 (2011), no. 3, 535–542, doi:[10.1112/jtopol/jtr011](https://doi.org/10.1112/jtopol/jtr011)

**(note that even though there is an arxiv version with the same title, subject and author [arxiv:/abs/1001.4790](https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.4790), the methods used are different and the proof in question doesn't appear)**. It says

[image: excerpt from paper]

where $P \to X$ is a $\mathbb C P^\infty$-principal bundle, corresponding to a twist $p \in H^3(X,\mathbb Z) \cong [X, K(\mathbb Z,3)]$ and $K$ is the $K$-theory spectrum. You can ignore the first map $K_*(\mathbb C P^\infty) \otimes K_*(P) \to K_*(P \times \mathbb C P^\infty)$, since this is "just" the Künneth theorem for (untwisted) $K$-theory. **What I'm interested in is how the three maps induce maps on twisted $K$-theory, and how the maps induced by the actions are equalized by the induced map of the third map**.

I've rewritten the first "equalized by" maps and put them into a diagram.

[image: map between coequaliser]

The symbols I used are chosen to comply better with the literature (in the second part of this question), i.e.  $\Pi=\mathbb C P^\infty, k=K$. Notice that the associated bundle/Borel construction is morally "adding zero", since by associativity we can cancel a term in the top row in the left column and middle column again. Anyway, The definition the author uses for twisted $K$-theory is as follows:

[image: definition the author uses]

This suggests to me that when the author says "which are equalized by ..." he means to use that $K^-(-)$ is a functor between the respective categories, also respecting the maps $\bar{\alpha},\bar{\beta}$ over $\alpha, \beta$ or is there another reason for this? Going by this notation would lead us to plug the pairs of arrows $(\bar{\alpha},\alpha)$ and $(\bar{\beta},\beta)$ into the functor, which translates to

[image: rewritten diagram]

## Understanding the twisted K-theory functor:

As for the more general part of the question, see page 349 of

> J. P. May and J. Sigurdsson, *Parametrized Homotopy Theory*, Mathematical Surveys and Monographs Volume 132 (2006), [AMS page](https://bookstore.ams.org/surv-132), arXiv:[math/0411656](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0411656), ([pdf](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/EXTHEORY/MaySig.pdf#page=349))

Given the question, we are mainly interested in K-homology. The homology theories are defined in  20.2.4. This is for $X$ (and $J$) a param. spectrum and is furthermore the reduced case, so we have to adjoin a point (by the proof of 20.1.5.) to get to the unreduced version, and apply the suspension functor. In total, this reads as
$$
J_n(X) = \pi_n(r_!(J \wedge_B \sum\nolimits_B^\infty X_+)
$$

Using Definition 22.1.1 (with $G=e$, $\Pi=\Gamma$), we find ourselves in the slice category over $BK(\mathbb Z, 2) \cong K(\mathbb Z, 3)$. Now restricting to $\Pi$-principal bundles, a morphism between objects is just a continuous map between the base spaces $f: X  \to Y$, such that the "projection" maps (=classifying maps/twistings) commute. This "domain" category is worded similarly in Bai-Ling Wang's paper

> *Geometric cycles, index theory and twisted K-homology*, J. Noncommut. Geom. **2** (2008), 497–552, doi:[10.4171/JNCG/27](https://doi.org/10.4171/JNCG/27), arXiv:[0710.1625](https://arxiv.org/abs/0710.1625)

(notice that here $K$-groups = $K$-cohomology is discussed, but the category should be the same).

[image: classification]

The lower triangle is in said category, and the upper square is what I'm interested in (sort of). Curiously, these are not $\Pi$-maps (?), and thus the upper square is not in the category of $\Pi$-principal bundles. This would at least ensure that the map $\bar{f}$ determines the lower map, according to Husemöller's *Fibre bundles* (p. 43). The problems persists when we apply the associated bundle construction (this is 15.4. in the book)

[image: bundle diagram]

Because for one: Husemöller requires (p. 45) the morphisms to "come" from principal bundle morphisms, and on the other hand: The second action map with component $\mathbb C P^\infty \times K \to K$ can not be of this shape/come from a principal bundle map. Notice that in the last diagram the nodes in the top row used 22.1.4 from the book. So the question is how an arbitrary function in the top row relates to $f$ and how twisted $K$-theory behaves with respect to it. The top row is a map of (parametrized) spectra, and at least in the unparametrized case, maps of spectra induce natural transformations between the respective (co-)homology theories (e.g. 8.39 of Switzer).

Two additional sources on parametrized spectra:

- May's talk titled "[What are parametrized spectra good for?](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/TALKS/MichiganPrint.pdf)"  (p. 16, 30, 37 etc.)
- Lind's *[Notes On Parametrized Spectra](https://jlind.yourweb.csuchico.edu/papers/notes_parametrized_spectra.pdf)*

**Edit: Thanks to Arun Debray, there is no need to change the site anymore to view the images etc.**

Comment: "If need be, I can also provide a ref to it." Yes please. A screen grab of an article is less useful than having access to the actual document. I had a search using key phrases and couldn't find the paper myself.

Comment: Thank you for your additions and clean up, David Roberts. I added a link to the journal article.

Comment: You have a map $K \wedge P_+ \to K \wedge_{S^0[\mathbb{C}P^{\infty}]} P_+$; now apply homotopy groups to both sides. The left is $K_*(P)$, by definition, and the right is $K^P_*(X)$, by definition. (I changed notation to make it a bit clearer where all the objects live- the map I wrote is the second displayed map in your screenshot.)

Comment: @Excalibur you're welcome. Thanks for both links, and noting the specific and pertinent differences between them.